# The files created and pushed from local repo are not physically visible in master repo in Git

Tags: git

I am new to Git and just started exploring it.

First I created a Git repository in `C:\GitMasterRepo` by command

```
git init
```

Then I cloned this repo in `D:\GitLocalRepo` as well as `D:\GitSecondLocalRepo`.

Then I added a new file `TheFile.txt` in `D:\GitLocalRepo` and commit and push to master repo.

I can see the new file by git pull in `D:\GitSecondLocalRepo`.

But the new file is not physically visible in the master repo (`C:\GitMasterRepo`) from where I cloned all the local repo.

Please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do `git init` or `git init --bare`? It is most probably the latter. A bare repository doesn't have a working directory and you won't see the files in the repo. Repositories that act as "master" - the ones you push to - should remain bare.

Comment: I did git init.
But I can't see any file physically.

Comment: @BhawanishankarPanda - By default you cannot push to a branch of non-bare repo that is checked out. What is the branch that is checked out in `C:\GitMasterRepo`. You can find it by running `git branch` or `git status`

Comment: Output of git branch in C:\GitMasterRepo is * master

By default I was not able to push anything to this master repo. Then I changed git configs for this. push.default to simple

Comment: @BhawanishankarPanda - Are you on branch named `branch`? Try doing `git checkout master` from the master repo.

Comment: The branch is master.. It was a typo in the previous comment..
git checkout master is giving response "Already in master"